# Small grey streak on screen visible with black background

Tags: display, pixels

I don't know how or why but I recently started noticing a small grey streak visible on my screen with a dark or black background. What is this? And what can I do to fix this?

[image: monitor]

Comment: It lools like a comet ;) Have you tried cleaning your screen?

Comment: Yep. The actual streak isn't as bright as in the picture but it's still there. I tried cleaning but I think it's something with the display because I can't feel any physical trail or smudge on the area where the streak is.

Comment: What kind of screen is it? LCD or LED laptop screen?. A monitor of some kind? As it there all the time? Have you restarted?

Comment: This is my laptop's built-in screen. I'm not sure if it's lcd or led. I've noticed it for a few weeks now but I'm sure it wasn't there before. Of course I've tried restarting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very very sorry to inform that probably you have a defect on your monitor. I believe this line is in fixed position. The monitor pixels are sitting on a matrix that when crossed, it lights up. One of the line (usually vertical lines) representing a column of pixels have lost signal, causing this gray streak on your screen. If the monitor is in factory warranty time, just take it to a technician that can see for it.

Comment: Oh ok. I'll try to have it checked then. What annoys me is that this is the second time I've brought in my laptop under warranty. This is actually a replacement of the original due to another defect caused by dead pixels. The last time I had it replaced, it took 2 months before they sent in a replacement and I'm not very willing to spend that much time without a laptop again.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, This problem wion't affect the useability of your system or applications, but sometimes may cause misreading, when characters get mixed in that line.